# T-SQL simple transform

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-transform

I  would like to transpose data returned from a SQL query in the manner outlined in the code below.

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(RowId INT, ColumnName VARCHAR(20), ColumnValue VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES 
(0, 'First Name', 'David'),
(1, 'First Name', 'Sarah'),
(0, 'Last Name', 'Jones'),
(1, 'Last Name', 'Vaughan')
```

I would like to produce a result set like this:

```
[RowID] | [First Name] | [Last Name]
   0    |    David     | Jones
   1    |    Sarah     | Vaughan
```

Preferably on SQL Server 2016

Comment: Please update your question title to represent the technical question... as it stands its meaningless.

Comment: You already know that you need to pivot - and that requires an aggregate even if it doesn't "seem suitable". The bigger issue is that you have a table that logically represents an EAV (Entity Attribute Value) design - which is something that requires more than basic programming skills. Much depends on how many values you expect to find in the column named "ColumnName". You show two different values - is that just the tip of the iceberg here?

Comment: `MAX` and `MIN` are aggregates, and works on text also

Answer (score 3):

Conditional aggregation offers more flexibility/control (+1 Stu), but if you are looking for a simple PIVOT...

Remember to "FEED" your PIVOT with only the required columns.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  #TempTable
 Pivot ( max(ColumnValue) for ColumnName in ( [First Name],[Last Name] ) ) pvt
```

**Results**

```
RowId   First Name  Last Name
0       David       Jones
1       Sarah       Vaughan
```

Comment: Thank you @John-Cappelletti, I did not know that about how to use PIVOT by feeding the required columns. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You are after a *Pivot*, there are literally hundreds of examples of doing this on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

However it's pretty simple to implement a conditional case like so:

```
select RowId,
    Max(case when ColumnName='First Name' then ColumnValue end) [First Name],
    Max(case when ColumnName='Last Name' then ColumnValue end) [Last Name]
from #TempTable
group by RowId
```

If you have more values you can can add these following the same pattern.

Comment: Thank you @Stu, I added the RowID for the purposes of posting the question here. But seeing your answer I can add it into my original query. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on from what I learned from @John-Cappelletti answer I had a fiddle around and came up with this solution that combines an XML Path query to help build a dynamic-sql query. This works for an unknown number of ColumnName values.

Posting it here as it may be of use to others

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(RowId int, ColumnName VARCHAR(20), DataValue VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES 
(0, 'First Name', 'David'),
(1, 'First Name', 'Sarah'),
(0, 'Last Name', 'Jones'),
(1, 'Last Name', 'Vaughan'),
(0, 'Age', '100'),
(1, 'Age', '50')

-- Get the column names in the format [Name 1], [Name 2]
-- as required for the Pivot query
DECLARE @ColumnNames VARCHAR(MAX) = (
        SELECT DISTINCT '[' + ColumnName + ']' + ',' AS 'data()'
        FROM #TempTable
        FOR XML path('')
        )

--- Remove the trailing comma (must be a better way to do this)
SET @ColumnNames = LEFT(@ColumnNames, LEN(@ColumnNames) - 1)

--- Build the Pivot query
DECLARE @SqlQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = 
        'Select *
        From  #TempTable
        Pivot ( max(DataValue) for ColumnName in (' + @ColumnNames + ') ) pvt'

EXEC(@SqlQuery)
```

Comment: Well done.  There are a couple of tweaks.   Use QUOTENAME() and STUFF()  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=453aecf2501c488ef6e6550f6ed498d3

Comment: QUOTENAME() will handle the []'s  and STUFF() will remove the LEADING comma (vs trailing)